# How to parse Japanese DateTime strings containing era to DateTime objects?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo

I'm trying to convert a Japanese DateTime string in the format `g yyyyMMdd` to a DateTime object. However, this seems to be throwing an exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` Here's the code I'm using

```
var cal = new JapaneseCalendar();
var jaJP = new CultureInfo("ja-JP", true);
jaJP.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = cal;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = jaJP;

var str = DateTime.Today.ToString();
var parsed = DateTime.Parse(str);   //Works

str = DateTime.Today.ToString("g yyyyMMdd");
parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(str,"g yyyyMMdd",jaJP);  //Does not works
```

Any suggestions what I might be missing here?

Comment: For a proper test you must use `DateTime.ToString("g yyyyMMdd",jaJP);` method.

Comment: So using that culture to format the date with "g yyyyMMdd" results in something like "令和 020527" where as the result with out the format is "令和2年5月27日 0:00:00" So you're losing information with that format and the result cannot be parsed back to a `DateTime`.

Comment: @Dialecticus Since they set the thread culture to that they don't need to pass it to `ToString`.

Comment: What do the dates you're actually trying to parse look like?

Comment: It looks like it will only parse if the numbers are separated somehow.  So a format like "g yy MM dd" works (note you don't need yyyy since the years are how long an emperor reigned and that's unlikely to ever be more than 2 digits)  So you might need to do some work up front to separate them so you can use a format that will work.

Comment: I debugged this further and it seems that the separators are not a problem. The issue somehow seems to lie with the use of `JapaneseCalendar`. If I comment out the line `jaJP.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = cal;` the parsing works.